# Forwarding a file upload

Tags: http, file-upload, go, multipartform-data

I'm working on an api endpoint in go that will accept an upload and then immediately forward to another API.  I don't want to write the file to disk anywhere, but I'm not sure storing the file temporarily in memory the way I have is correct either.  All the examples that I can find deal with saving the file to disk.  I've posted what I'm doing below.  The response I get back from the second API is that I failed to post a file, but I can see that it is receiving the "userID" field.  Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong as well as possibly advise if this is the best way to go about this?

Route Handler

```
func (r *Routes) forwardFile(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){ 
    parameters := mux.Vars(req)
    userID := parameters["userID"]

    const maxFileSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 // 1MB

    // pull in the uploaded file into memory
    req.ParseMultipartForm(maxFileSize)


    file, fileHeader, err := req.FormFile("fileUpload")
    if err != nil {
        encodeResponse(w, req, response{obj: nil, err: err})
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    success, err := service.DoForwardFile(userID, file, fileHeader)
    encodeResponse(w, req, response{obj: success, err: err})
}
```

Service Handler

```
func (b *base) DoForwardFile(userID int, file multipart.File, fileHeader *multipart.FileHeader) (FileForwardedResponse, error) {
    // start building our request to forward the file
    var resp *http.Response
    defer func() {
        if resp != nil {
            resp.Body.Close()
        }
        reportStat.Complete(0)
    }()

    // build a form body
    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    bodyWriter := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    // add form fields
    bodyWriter.WriteField("userID", userID)

    // add a form file to the body
    fileWriter, err := bodyWriter.CreateFormFile("fileUpload", fileHeader.Filename)
    if err != nil {
        return FileForwardedResponse{}, err
    }
    // copy the file into the fileWriter
    _, err = io.Copy(fileWriter, file)
    if err != nil {
        return FileForwardedResponse{}, err
    }

    // Close the body writer
    bodyWriter.Close()

    // build request url
    apiURL := fmt.Sprintf("%s/v2/users/%d/files", config.APIURL, userID)

    // send request
    client := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Second * 10}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", apiURL, body)
    resp, err = client.Do(req)

    ... 


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the `Content-Type` for the request. Even if the header gets set automatically to `multipart/form-data`, it's missing the data boundary.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, body)
if err != nil {
    return FileForwardedResponse{}, err
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", bodyWriter.FormDataContentType())
...
```

Comment: Thanks JimB!  That was it!  I knew it had to be something simple. :D